# The difference of meaning between 'stop'and 'prevent'

Tags: meaning, grammar

I want to know the difference of meaning between 'stop'and 'prevent'.

Comment: Driving into a brick wall will **stop** your car very quickly whereas applying the brakes properly will **prevent** you from hitting the wall.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of **stop** ([Oxford Dictionnary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stop)) is

> (Of an event, action, or process) come to an end; cease to happen

The definition of **prevent** ([Oxford Dictionnary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prevent)) is

> Keep (something) from happening

So the difference between the two is the moment you act. If the action has already started, you *stop* it. Otherwise you *prevent* it.